# EvictedUnfetched memcached

Tags: memcached

I am currently using 1.4.4 compiled version of memcache in RHEL distro & from monitoring point of view:

```
memcached-tool 10.0.0.5:11211 display    # shows slabs
memcached-tool 10.0.0.5:11211 stats      # shows general stats
```

These two commands are great for monitoring stats, slabs stats, etc..

while exploring options that amazon elasticcache provides:
[docs.aws.amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheMetrics.Memcached.html)

In short, amazon provides

```
EvictedUnfetched    The number of valid items evicted from the least recently used cache (LRU) which were never touched after being set.
```

I dont see this option available in memcache-tool, being aware that it says it is available for 1.4.14 in above doc,

Is there anyway to getting this stat on memcached 1.4.4 [not in elasticcache i am looking for that stat in compiled memached 1.4.4 in RHEL]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this stat is available in memcached 1.4.4 but it is possible to view all available stats with the telnet client.

```
$ telnet <host> 11211
telnet> stats
```